# Figure environment not working properly

Tags: graphics, floats

I am trying to save space on my poster by placing two figures (one long-ish, one flat-ish) side-by-side in the same column. Everything I've read online says to use the figure environment, but for some reason when I use it, the images do not appear. I would also like to have labels at the bottom of the figures (as they do now). Below is a MWE. Right now, the center environment puts the images in their separate space, and I would like them side-by-side. I can't figure out why the figure environment won't work specifically in this poster document, I don't seem to have issues in regular files.

```
\documentclass[a0,landscape]{a0poster}

\usepackage{multicol} % This is so we can have multiple columns of text side-by-side
\columnsep=100pt % This is the amount of white space between the columns in the poster
\columnseprule=3pt % This is the thickness of the black line between the columns in the poster

\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor} % Specify colors by their 'svgnames', for a full list of all colors available see here: http://www.latextemplates.com/svgnames-colors

\newlength\runit
\runit=1cm

\edef\Radius#1{#1\runit}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{authblk}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{times} % Use the times font
%\usepackage{palatino} % Uncomment to use the Palatino font
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for including images
\graphicspath{{figures/}} % Location of the graphics files
\usepackage{booktabs} % Top and bottom rules for table
\usepackage[font=small,labelfont=bf]{caption} % Required for specifying captions to tables and figures
\usepackage{amsfonts, amsmath, amsthm, amssymb} % For math fonts, symbols and environments
\usepackage{wrapfig} % Allows wrapping text around tables and figures

%some commands

\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}

%some text

\begin{center}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=85mm]{file1}
\captionof{figure}{caption1}
\end{center}

\begin{center}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=75mm]{file2}
\captionof{figure}{caption2}
\end{center}


%some text here

\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Try using the `figure` environment instead of `center`.

Comment: When I do, the graphics disappear. This is the problem I'm having.

Comment: A blank line is a paragraph break. Don't leave a blank line if you want them side-by-side. And don't use `center`. Or, at least, if you use `center` put *both* figures inside it. And `\centering` is doing nothing. Or use a `minipage` and `\centering` for example.

Comment: By the way, your code does not compile. Can you please fix it?

Answer (score 4):

Something like this?

[image: side-by-side images in one column]

```
\documentclass[a0,landscape]{a0poster}

\usepackage{multicol} % This is so we can have multiple columns of text 
                      % side-by-side
\setlength{\columnsep}{100pt} % This is the amount of white space between the 
                              % columns in the poster
\setlength{\columnseprule}{3pt} % This is the thickness of the black line 
                                % between the columns in the poster
\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for including images
\usepackage[font=small,labelfont=bf]{caption} % Required for specifying 
                                              % captions to tables and figures

\begin{document}

\begin{multicols}{2}% you must specify the number of columns!

\begin{center}% centre whole block
  \begin{minipage}{.5\linewidth}% left side
    \centering% centre within block
    \includegraphics[width=85mm]{example-image-a}% standard image
    \captionof{figure}{caption1}
  \end{minipage}%
  \begin{minipage}{.5\linewidth}% right side
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=75mm]{example-image-b}
    \captionof{figure}{caption2}
  \end{minipage}%
\end{center}

\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```